# .NET PricipalContext.ValidateCredentials always returns FALSE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, windows-authentication, principalcontext

I have Domain authentication implemented in the ASP.NET project. Using 4.5 .Net frameworks, 3.0.1 Microsoft.Owin dependencies.

Here is how I am validating the user trying to login:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, username, password))
{
    ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindByName(username);
    if (user != null)
    {
        var signInStatus = context.ValidateCredentials(username, password, ContextOptions.SimpleBind);
        // next code based on signInStatus value 
    }
}
```

I tried many answers on Stack Overflow but nothing worked for me. Any help will be very much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I looked into the `PrincipalContext.validateCredentials` [method](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/src/System/DirectoryServices/AccountManagement/Context.cs#L327) and found that it returns false when app receives `LdapException`. Does anyone know why LdapException comes? Am I missing something in configuration?

Comment: What is the `ErrorCode` value in the `LdapException`?

Comment: @Jackdaw, it is `ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE = 0x31`.

Comment: Your validation process seems correct. Therefore, there is nothing to do but consider all possible reasons. Look at the error description [invalidCredentials (49)](https://ldap.com/ldap-result-code-reference-core-ldapv3-result-codes/#rc-invalidCredentials). And try to check all the listed problems step by step.